# How do you pass copies of a generic object to separate async methods in Java?

Tags: java, jackson

Looking for a way to SAFELY implement something like this on a generic parameter in Java;

```
  public <I, O> O method(final I param){

    I copy1 = //make first copy of param;
    I copy2 = //make another copy of param;

    asyncMutatingThread1(copy1); //mutates copy1 while processing and saves to db-01
    asyncMutatingThread2(copy2); //mutates copy2 while processing and saves to db-02

    //continue using param here in main thread ...
    return process(param); // returns result of type <O>
  }
```

How would one go about this while keeping `param` intact?

**Noteworthy:**

- I have ***no control & cannot predict the the types*** that will be passed as `param` so, implementing custom copies doesn't seem feasible.
- I have tried doing a deep copy using Jackson, but that comes with its own serialization/deserialization challenges - for example, classes nested inside a collection within an object do not get deserialized properly without registering custom deserializer(s) for every type ***(which - well, I still do not know and cannot predict)***.

Any ideas or alternatives?

Comment: You *have* to know something about the type. There is no arbitrary "deep-copy this object" method in Java (there's `Object.clone`, but that's specifically designed to throw an exception most of the time). Your `I` type is going to have to implement some sort of copyable interface.

Comment: It's too short to post as an answer, but, I do have one for you. "It is impossible". Take a step back, what are you trying to accomplish? "I can solve whatever problem I have if only I can make copies of any object" is not going to lead to a satisfactory result.